# Why does my imageview disappear on an orientation change with different layout file for landscape?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation, android-layout-weight

I have a layout file for list items in portrait mode. This works very well at fitting the screen, keeping the same size for images and maintaining the aspect-ratio:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
       </LinearLayout>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

I then have a pretty similar file for the landscape version, only I use weights so that the image takes up half the width of the screen (the aim being to produce a similar sized square image). There is a relativelayout next to this with a weight of 1 also. Shouldn't both of these occupy half of the screen now?

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">  
    <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           </LinearLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp">
           ...
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Well instead, I can't see the image or the text. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update** Here is the code from my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new CardFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Here is where I set the imageView's resource

```
 public class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    CakeImageToLoad imageToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, CakeImageToLoad p){bitmap=b;imageToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(imageToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

private static Bitmap convertToBitmap(byte[] data) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code from your activity?

Comment: The layouts you posted here make no sense. Why are `adjustViewBounds` and `scaleType` on the LinearLayout when they should be on the ImageView? And in the second layout, why is the RelativeLayout outside the LinearLayout? Or ar e they both inside something else? Please post the full layouts exactly as you have them in your xml files.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter">
...
```

You have 2 layout_width, i guess one of them was supposed to be weight.

And i think that to occupy half the scree the Relative layout should also have width 0 and weight 1

Comment: Sorry, Alexandru, I have been trying to post the minimum amount of code for my question, but have made some mistakes. I have set the width to weight in my question. And I already do have a weight of 1 and width of 0 in the relativelayout. Will update again

Comment: Where do you set the imageResource to the ImageView?

Comment: In the CardFragment class.

Comment: Post that also :)))

Comment: Will do. Not at my machine just now